# CSS: transitioning a width in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have an element that has the html of this:

```
<div class="email-section full-width">
   <video src="/////"></video>
   <button>Press Me</button>
</div>
```

The button has a javascript handler on it that removes the `full-width` class from the div.  However, the width doesn't gradually get smaller.  It waits the 3 seconds then snaps it to 50%.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong with it.

```
.email-section {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 50%;
    transition: width 3s ease;

    &.full-width {
      flex-grow: 1;
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `flex-grow` property:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.email-section').toggleClass('full-width');
});
```

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.email-section {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

.email-section.full-width {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="email-section">
    <button>Press Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls3wkcob/

You can technically keep the `width` property instead of switching to `flex-basis`, but since it's a flex child, `flex-basis` is probably better to use.

Fiddle using `width`:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls3wkcob/1/